# 好ましいタグの名前とは:略称が良いか、正称が良いか、それとも俗語か。

Tags: 討議, タグ

タグの名前の付け方について質問(もしくは問題提起)です。

タイトルの通り、タグは本来どのような名前が好ましいかという話です。

つまり、ヘルプの例にもあるように恐らく多くの人は検索では`css`と調べると思いますが、タグシノニムで`cascading-style-sheets`というようなタグにされるのが良いか`css`のままがよいのかという質問です。

私の意見としては、タグは検索の為にどのような物が出来ても良いのですが、タグシノニムによって正称に行き着くべきと考えています。なぜなら正称こそがその物の名前であり、間違える心配がほぼ無いからです。

皆さんの意見、もしくはヘルプセンターや質問は一通り調べたのですが、もう何かルールがある場合は教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 4):

タグを見てタグの意味を悩まずに理解できるかどうか、という点で見るのも大切だと思います。その名前が一般的に普及しているかどうかをGoogleやBingのような検索エンジンに頼るのも1つの手だと僕は思います。

例としてあげられている`cascading-style-sheets`と`css`の場合で見ると、正式名称としては前者ですが、一般的によく見かける名称としては後者だと思われます。
両者をGoogleで検索した場合に`css`では約627,000,000件に対して`cascading-style-sheets`は約10,300,000件と明らかに差があります。

`javascript`と`js`とでは人によって分かれる内容ではありますが、こちらもGoogleで検索した場合に`javascript`では約1,950,000,000件に対して`js`は約701,000,000件とこちらも明らかに差があります。

もちろん以上の2点で検索した場合にノイズがある程度かかりますが、正式名称の方が明らかに少ない(or 多い)場合には参考になると思います。

Comment: 目安にはなりそうですね。私の好きなMercurialとhgだと、hgではレイザーラモンとか出てきて困ってしまうというケースも他でもたまにありそうですがｗ（それ以上に元素記号なので多いのかな）

Answer (score 3):

個人的には短い方がいいと思いますが、なにが最適なのかは難しいところですね、

タグは複数並ぶことがありますので長いと横幅を取ってしまいます。まずこの部分で短い方がいいだろうと思います。

もう一つは視認性といいますか、`cascading-style-sheets`と`css`でどちらがすぐにそれをイメージできるかといえば、私に限って言えば後者です。
こちらは短ければいいのかと言われるとそれも要素にはありますが、見慣れていることの方がより重要なのでしょうね。

端的に言えば、わかりやすくて邪魔にならない方をタグとした方がいいと思うので、
略語も積極的に利用してよいとおもいます。

現状、`javascript`が`js`ではなく`javascript`なんですね。

俗語についてはどういう俗語か思い浮かばなかったので保留します。
（アップル製品を林檎とかいうことなんでしょうか？javascriptとECMAScript？）

Answer (score 1):

現実的に「最も受け入れられて、最もよく使われる表現」がプラクティカルではないかと思います。

cascading-style-sheets　と　CSS　ならば圧倒的に後者であろうし、
javascript と JS　であれば、前者であれば微妙ではありますが前者であると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Google Trends も参考になると思います。
例えば・・

- [`amazon web service` vs `aws`](http://www.google.co.jp/trends/explore#q=amazon%20web%20service%2Caws)
  -> **aws** の方が圧倒的です
- [`cascading style sheets` vs `css`](http://www.google.co.jp/trends/explore#q=cascading%20style%20sheets%2Ccss)
  -> こちらも **css** の方が良さそうです
- [`google app engine` vs `gae`](http://www.google.co.jp/trends/explore#q=google%20app%20engine%2Cgae)
  -> **gae** が多いです。
- [`javascript` vs `js`](http://www.google.co.jp/trends/explore#q=javascript%2C%20js)
  -> こちらは **javascript** が多いですが、「予測」を見ると **js** と入れ替わる可能性がありますね・・・

個人的にはGoogle等の検索エンジンでStackoverflowがヒットしてくれると助かるので、SEOに強そうな名付けを優先してもらえると解決が速いかなと思います。

Answer (score 0):

多くの利用者が認知している、**入門書に使われている表記**が適切だと思います。

具体的な決定方法としては、入門のワードと一緒に検索することで、どちらを採用すべきが判断できるかと思います。

[例１](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=gae%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80)
[例２](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=js%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80)
[例３](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=cascading%20style%20sheets%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80)
aws については検索結果に優位な差が見られなかったので、[曖昧さ回避](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS)の観点から正式名称を採用するべきかと思います。

[俗語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%97%E8%AA%9E)はあまりいい表現ではないと思います。