# twitter-bootstrap タグの bootstrap タグへのマージの提案

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, 完了, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

### 提案内容

[twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) を [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) へマージし、 Bootstrap に関する質問を [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) タグに統一することを提案します。

---

### 提案理由

質問投稿数から、 [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) タグは明らかに [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) よりも使用されておらず、同様の意味を持つタグが 2 つあることによりタグ付けの際に混乱をきたす可能性があるためです。

また、 Twitter Bootstrap という名称はもはや Bootstrap のプロジェクトで使用されておらず、 Bootstrap を Twitter Bootstrap と呼ぶことは、公式サイトにおいても誤った例として挙げられています。

> ### Name<sup>[[1]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/about/brand/#name)</sup>
>
> The project and framework should always be referred to as Bootstrap. No Twitter before it, no capital s, and no abbreviations except for one, a capital B.

---

### 関連投稿

- [好ましいタグの名前とは:略称が良いか、正称が良いか、それとも俗語か。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1481/32986)
  今回の質問の焦点は「重複した 2 つのタグがあるとき、どのように対処するか」というところにあると考えているので、この投稿を関連投稿として載せておきます。

---

### 参考

1. [Brand guidelines · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/about/brand/)

Answer (score 6):

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

[bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) を手で [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) [android-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-bootstrap) などに付け替えたり、単に消したりしました。ついでに [bootstrap4](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap4) などのタグを [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4) に統一しました。

---

[bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) へマージするのには反対です。代わりに、今ついている [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) タグを他の適切なタグへ付け替える ([burniate する](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)) ことと、今後は Bootstrap に関して [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) のみを使うことを提案します。

理由は以下の通りです：

- 日本語版 SO の [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) のタグ wiki は現状 Bootstrap フレームワークに関する説明しかしていませんが、この界隈には他にも本来の[「ブートストラップ」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)という意味でこの言葉を使うことがあります。タグをマージしてしまうと、将来「ブートストラップ」を意味するタグを付けたくなったときに [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) を使えず不便かもしれません。また、一応 [ブートストラップ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%96%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%83%83%e3%83%97) や [bootstrapping](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) というタグを作って使えば良いのですが、それらと [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) が共存すると分かりにくいです。
- [Android Bootstrap](https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap) というものがあり、実際 1 件これについての質問が[あります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33216/19110)。
- 英語版 SO では [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) が burniate されており、そこからどうするかというところで議論が止まっています。英語版とのタグの整合性をなるべく保つためにも、[bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) へのマージは避けた方が良さそうです。

  - [Bootstrap tags revisited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298095/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

英語版では更に [bootstrap-framework](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework) を新設して [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) をそちらへマージするのはどうか、というアイディアが出ていますが、そこまでしちゃって良いのか僕には判断ついていません。とりあえず「公式には Twitter Bootstrap じゃなくて Bootstrap と呼んで欲しいと言っている」という点を除けば [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) でも不便しないので、良いかなと。

Comment: 今更ですが、 `bootstrap4` タグも `twitter-bootstrap-4` とするのか、 `bootstrap4` のままにするのか、対応が必要になってきそうです。参考までに、英語版では `bootstrap4` になっているようです。

Comment: 「burninate」は必要でしょうか。
例えば以下の手順では駄目ですか？
〔1. [tag:bootstrap] が付いた質問の中でTwitterのBootstrapとは違う意味で使われている質問のタグ付けを変更する（おそらく1、2件）〕
〔2. 残った [tag:bootstrap] が付いた質問を [tag:twitter-bootstrap] へマージ〕 
〔3. 必要であれば、[tag:bootstrap] を [tag:twitter-bootstrap] の別名にする。
もしくは[ブロック](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag)する。〕

Comment: bootstrap という言葉にはデザインシステムの bootstrap の他に OS のブートやブートストラップ問題、ブートスラップ法などの bootstrap があり、どれも bootstrap と呼ばれていて知名度も低くはないので、[bootstrap] の他タグへのマージには反対です。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ええ、その点のnekketsuuuさんの意見は理解しています。
そういったTwitter Bootstrap以外の意味で [tag:bootstrap] が使われている質問のタグを付け替えた後に残っているのは、Twitter Bootstrap の意味で使われている質問だけなので、その時点でマージしてはどうか、という提案です。

Comment: @mjy タグの付け替えだけのためにマージの機能を単体で使って、編集履歴に残すことなく一気に付け替えてしまいたいということですよね。今 [bootstrap] が付いている質問は 76 件で、どうせ Twitter Bootstrap かどうかを確認しながらひとつずつ見ていくのであれば手で付け替えてしまえば良い件数かなと思っていました。ホームのフィードが編集ログで埋まってしまうのが気になるという感じでしょうか？

Comment: 私なりの代案を出しましたが、ご覧の通りでしたので、nekketsuuu さんに進めていただきたいと思います。なお、言ってみたはいいが、やるとなると面倒、ということも有ると思います。その際は、遠慮なく撤回して構わないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

サイトのトップに表示される一覧がこれの関係の編集で埋め尽くされている状態でした。結果、本来表示されていたはずの投稿も押し流されています。

しかもこれ投稿を見ると手作業で実施された編集のようです。

そこまでしてやる価値のある作業だったんでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りと思いますが、それを解決する私の案は支持いただけなかったので、仕方が無いです。
6票対、0票ですから。コミュニティーの意思は明確だったと思います。

Answer (score 0):

追記 2024-02-09: 私の案に票は入らず、完全な否決といってよいでしょう。nekketsuuu さんの案で進めていただければと思います。

---

#### 手作業での付け替え（burniate）でなく、マージを提案します

手作業で付け替えを行なう案が出されていますが、

- 面倒である
- トップページが埋まってしまう
- 精査の必要は無い

という理由で気が進みません。より簡易で迅速な方法として、[bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) を [twitter-bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) へマージすることを提案します。

##### 面倒である

コメントで少し議論いたしましたが、

> 76 件で、どうせ Twitter Bootstrap かどうかを確認しながらひとつずつ見ていくのであれば手で付け替えてしまえば良い件数

という意見をいただいており、それは一理あると思います。

しかし結局のところ、誰がいつ行なうのかを定めずに負担の多寡は論じられません。現実に4年以上が経ち、誰も行なおうとしておらず、私もやりたくありません。

##### トップページが埋まってしまう

このサイトの流量ですと、アクティブな質問を上から見ていく、といった利用方法のユーザーも多いと思います。飽和状態の英語版などとは事情が違う部分です。

そこで上位をささいな編集で埋めてしまうことに、気がすすみません。せっかくの投稿や編集が見逃されがちになります。また、更新をチェックしなくなるユーザーもいるでしょう。

##### 精査の必要は無い

[bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)タグの説明には

> BootstrapはウェブサイトやWebアプリケーションを作成するフロントエンドWebアプリケーションフレームワークです。

とあり、殆ど（もしかしたら全て）の質問はこの意味で [bootstrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) を使用しています。よって、マージの前にざっと確認するだけで十分だと思います。

（ちなみに、[Android Bootstrap](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap)はTwitter Bootstrapのノウハウをそのまま使用できるように意図されたものなので、質問者さんもTwitter Bootstrapを意識してタグ付けした可能性が高いと思います。是非はともかく。）

もちろん、手作業であれば、より確実な精査が行われることと思いますが、今回の作業の主旨はそこでは無いはずです。精査したい方がいらっしゃれば、マージ前に行なっても構いませんし、マージ後にも可能です（希望が有ればマージ前に記録し、マージされた質問のリストを提供いたします）。